# Is a mirror site like this legit?

Tags: discussion

While googling myself, I found this site: http://blogs.candoerz.com/qa/. It looks like it is collecting Stack Exchange sites' questions and answers, and presenting them as its own content.

Is this legitimate?

Comment: Well, all SE sites (or rather, their content) are CC-BY-SA-licensed, but I doubt this site correctly follows the "BY" clause of that license.

Comment: @Sven what do you mean? If you mean reference there is, in questions view, e.g. [here](http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/306578/how-to-check-403-forbidden-error-page.aspx) there is a link Question Reference poitning to the original question on SF.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yeah, you are right, I missed that, but I hadn't any motivation to look *that* closely to such kind of site.